# How do I avoid a GridView's Gridlines changing color when applying a class to a cell on the RowDataBound event?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, rowdatabound

In my website, I have a page with a Gridview that I use to display some data. I capture the RowDataBound event, to find out if certain text is present in a cell. If it is, I color it green, else I color it red.

Here's the problem: the Gridview has horizontal gridlines only. When I change the color of the cell in RowDataBound (I'm actually changing the class), the gridlines take on the color applied. I cannot revert it back, no matter what I try (looping through all cells and setting border-color). Please help.

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Contains("monkey"))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("class", "monkey bold");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("class", "nomonkey bold");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

The style is as follows:

```
.monkey
{
    color: #009900;
    border-color: black;
}

.nomonkey
{
    color: red;
    border-color: black;
}
```

The border-color property seems to have no effect.

The GridView is defined as:

```
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="False" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView2_DataBound" CssClass="reportGrid"> 
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#2F76B8" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#2F76B8" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFFFF" ForeColor="#222222" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, and couldn't tempt anyone into answering it either, so I worked around it by adding a span inside the cell, and setting its style like so:

```
            if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Contains("monkey"))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("monkey", "<span class=\"monkey\">monkey</span> ");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing. An alternative would be to add a Label control and set the properties on that instead.

Rather than using a BoundField, use a TemplateField. Assuming that your data is returning an indexable item:

```
<asp:GridViewControl runat="server" ID="GridView2" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Field0" DataField="[0]" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Field1" DataField="[1]" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monkey1" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monkey2" />
</asp:GridViewControl>
```

Then in the code-behind:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var data_item = e.Row.DataItem; // Can use "as <type>;" if you know the type.
        if (data_item != null)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                var cell_content = new Label();
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cell_content);

                cell_content.Text = data_item[i];
                if (data_item[i].Contains("monkey"))
                {
                    cell_content.Attributes.Add("class", "monkey bold");
                }
                else
                {
                    cell_content.Attributes.Add("class", "nomonkey bold");
                }
            }
        }
```

Of course an alternative would be to add the Label in the TemplateField -> ItemTemplate declaration with an ID and use "Cells[i].FindControl("label_id")".